# Python / Django: envio de e-mails resultando em 535 (gmail funcionando)

Tags: python, django, envio-de-email

Possuo um formulário de contato na onde eu envio a mensagem para o administrador do sistema informando-o sobre a mesma. As informações de configuração de e-mail estão totalmente verificadas e corretas.

```
EMAIL_HOST='mail.xxx.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='no-reply@xxx.net'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='xxx'
EMAIL_PORT='25'
```

Para envio do formulário possuo um script em AJAX, que executa a função de disparo do e-mail. O seguinte erro é retornado:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /vendas/contato/
(535, 'Incorrect authentication data')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://xxx.net/vendas/contato/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError
Exception Value:    
(535, 'Incorrect authentication data')
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py in login, line 622
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/home/xxx/pythonenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/xxx/pythonenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/xxx/src/myproject']
Server time:    Seg, 26 Set 2016 17:08:45 -0300
```

Após alguns testes, verifiquei que ao inserir um e-mail do **gmail** por exemplo, o e-mail é enviado normalmente, outros domínios como o `xxx.net` ou `yyy.com.br` resultam no erro 535.

Alguem tem alguma idéia do que pode estar ocasionando isto?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é erro de autenticação do seu serviço de smtp.

Não é só colocar outro domínio de host e outro user e pronto. Você tem que olhar a documentação do novo serviço de smtp, ver qual é o endereço de host e a porta a ser utilizada.